# Method/Function To Update Multiple Properties Per One Control

Tags: c#, controls

I'm probably Googling or searching for the wrong task (or it's not possible).  Is there a way to pass a control, like a textbox and change multiple properties.  For an example, passing myTextOne into a method and set it to multiline, red text, etc.

I tried using a class approach for a textbox, where I could call a method that would manipulate multiple properties at the same time, then call the method on the textbox:

```
        private TextBox pText;
        public TextBox PText
        {
            get { return pText; }
            set { pText= value; }
        }

        public static UpdateProperties()
        {
            pText.Multiline= true;
            pText.BackColor = Color.White;
            //3RD property
        }

/// Calling it:
myTextOne = MyClass.UpdateProperties()
```

In general, changing properties line-by-line functions, but if there's any possibility of a repeat, it would save more time to just a method or some other function to update multiple properties, especially if this *may* be used for others.

Thanks.

Comment: Does that code compile?

Comment: If this is a webform, then i would create textbox control in aspx. Then in code you can simply call your functions. 

Something like : 

UpdateProperties()

Textbox you create in aspx is accessible in code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Just pass the control

Yes; you just need to provide an argument of the appropriate type.  For example:

```
static void UpdateProperties(System.Windows.Forms.Controls.TextBox textbox)
{
    textBox.BackColor = Color.White;
    textBox.MultiLine = true;
}
```

Then, in your main program

```
MyClass.UpdateProperties(PText);
```

### Or pass the control as an ancestor type

You can also define the parameter as a `Control` which allows you to pass any control, not just a textbox.  However, the function will only be able to set those properties that are common across all controls (such as `Text`).

```
static void UpdateText(System.Windows.Forms.Controls.Control control)
{
    control.Text = "Test";
}

//Main program
MyClass.UpdateText(PControl);
```

### Use an extension method

You can also use [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx) syntax, like this:

```
namespace MyExtensionMethodNamespace
{
    public class MyExtensionMethodClass
    {
        static public void UpdateProperties(this System.Windows.Forms.Controls.TextBox textbox)
        {
            textBox.BackColor = Color.White;
            textBox.MultiLine = true;
        }

        static public void UpdateText(this System.Windows.Forms.Controls.Control control)
        {
            control.Text = "Test";
        }
    }
}

//Main program
using MyExtensionMethodNamespace;

this.PTextBox.UpdateProperties();
this.PTextBox.UpdateText();
```

### Use fluent syntax

If you write the extension method so that it returns `this` you can use a fluent syntax, like this:

```
namespace MyExtensionMethodNamespace
{
    public class MyExtensionMethodClass
    {
        static public TextBox UpdateProperties(this TextBox textbox)
        {
            textBox.BackColor = Color.White;
            textBox.MultiLine = true;
            return textBox;
        }

        static public Control UpdateText(this Control control)
        {
            control.Text = "Test";
            return control;
        }
    }
}

//Main program
using MyExtensionMethodNamespace;

this.PTextBox.UpdateProperties().UpdateText();
```

This solution is nice because you can do all your updates in one line.

### Work with multiple controls at once

Once you have figured out how to do the above, you can modify it to work with more than one control at a time, like this:

```
namespace MyExtensionMethodNamespace
{
    public class MyExtensionMethodClass
    {
        static public IEnumerable<TextBox> UpdateProperties(this IEnumerable<TextBox> textboxes)
        {
            foreach( var textBox in textBoxes)
            {
                textBox.BackColor = Color.White;
                textBox.MultiLine = true;
            }
            return textBoxes;
        }

        static public IEnumerable<Control> UpdateText(this IEnumerable<Control> controls)
        {
            foreach ( var control in controls)
            {
                control.Text = "Test";
            }
            return controls;
        }
    }
}

//Main program
using MyExtensionMethodNamespace;

//Update three specific controls
new [] {myControl1, myControl2, myControl3}.UpdateProperties().UpdateText();    

//Update all controls on the form
this.Controls.UpdateProperties().UpdateText();

//Update all TextBox controls on the form
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>.UpdateProperties().UpdateText();
```

This can be helpful if you often find yourself updating more than one control at once.

### Use LINQ

And of course you can always use LINQ and pass a delegate.

```
using System.Linq;

//Set three specific controls
new[]{myControl1, myControl2, myControl2}.ToList().ForEach(a => {a.Text = "Test";  a.BackColor = Color.Red; a.MultiLine = true});

//Set all controls
this.Controls.ToList().ForEach(a => {a.Text = "Test";  a.BackColor = Color.Red; a.MultiLine = true});

//Set all TextBox controls
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>.ToList().ForEach(a => {a.Text = "Test";  a.BackColor = Color.Red; a.MultiLine = true});
```

This solution is nice because you don't have to write any helper functions at all.